# How to open deploy Confluent Platform for production uses (multiple nodes)?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I have setup the Confluent Platform in my local machine using Windows Subsystem for Linux. Confluent Platform is working fine and I tested it's local environment (for development only) using the `local` command like: `confluent local services start` (which will start all the services like zookeeper, kafka, connect, and the **control-center** also).

Now I want to test it on production environment (simply means not using `local` command). Basically, I want to run and use the same command like in local environment without `local` command.

I login using `confluent login` with credentials **My Mail ID** and **Password** which I created on Confluent's website.

Now I am getting these commands after `confluent`

```
yes@robin:/mnt/c/Users/robin$ confluent
Manage your Confluent Cloud.

Usage:
  confluent [command]

Available Commands:
  admin           Perform administrative tasks for the current organization.
  api-key         Manage the API keys.
  audit-log       Manage audit log configuration.
  cloud-signup    Sign up for Confluent Cloud.
  completion      Print shell completion code.
  connect         Manage Kafka Connect.
  context         Manage CLI configuration contexts.
  environment     Manage and select Confluent Cloud environments.
  help            Help about any command
  iam             Manage RBAC and IAM permissions.
  kafka           Manage Apache Kafka.
  ksql            Manage ksqlDB.
  local           Manage a local Confluent Platform development environment.
  login           Log in to Confluent Cloud or Confluent Platform.
  logout          Log out of Confluent Cloud.
  price           See Confluent Cloud pricing information.
  prompt          Add Confluent CLI context to your terminal prompt.
  schema-registry Manage Schema Registry.
  shell           Start an interactive shell.
  version         Show version of the Confluent CLI.

Flags:
      --version         Show version of the Confluent CLI.
  -h, --help            Show help for this command.
  -v, --verbose count   Increase verbosity (-v for warn, -vv for info, -vvv for debug, -vvvv for trace).
```

**Now**
I am not able to locate the **control-center**.

Can someone help if this is the correct way to login into Confluent Platform on-premise OR I have to use some other command to start all the services including **control-center**.

**Thanks, Robin.**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a browser to http://localhost:9021 . You shouldn't need to login or use the CLI after `confluent local services start`; however, this may not work in WSL2, as you need to forward a network port for your Windows OS browser to reach this environment.

The [local quickstart guide](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html#quickstart) should be followed instead, which uses Docker Compose (install Docker for Windows and enable WSL2 integration in its settings). Then a network port forward will be available without extra configuration.

Comment: Sorry to say but I think you didn't get my question. I did setup the Confluent Platform on WSL in WINDOWS and it's working fine. Also, I did hands on with LOCAL development environment.
Now, I want to use it in production with two or more brokers. How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear from your question. The confluent CLI explicitly says it's only for local development environment, which means only one broker. If you want a production setup outside of Docker or Kubernetes, I typically recommended Confluent's Ansible playbooks deployed onto a real Linux cluster, not a Windows environment. If you really wanted to use that login command, that's for Confluent **Cloud**, which completely replaces Control Center

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer ! One more closing question. What are the minus points when I deploy Confluent Platform using Windows Subsystem for Linux INSTEAD of real Linux environment.

Comment: @Robin The main downside is that it is virtualized and you need to mess with the network bridge using `netsh portproxy` commands to "expose" Kafka and related components outside any one Windows host. Same answer applies for using Docker/Kubernetes with WSL2 integration